# How does Laravel know if someone is an admin or normal user - Laravel Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am currently in the process of trying to understand how Laravel functions. And my biggest question is the authentication process. Lets say i have an admin panel and a user panel. I have a column in the "users" table for "user_type" and 1 = normal user and 2 = admin user. When a user logs into the user login form laravel checks the users info and makes sure that the type is 1 for a normal user login. If it is, it sets a session. But how do i check if the user logged is a admin or normal user. Any help is appreciated greatly! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your web.php you can do this:

```
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@determineLoginType')->middleware('guest');
```

And in your `LoginController.php` you can do something like this:

```
public function determineLoginType(Request $request)
{
    /** 
     * Here I am assuming that the email field on your user model is unique,
     * therefore I am retrieving that specific user by the email they provided 
     * at the login form
     */

    $user = \App\User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if ($user && $user->user_type == 2) { // Check if the user exists & check their type.
        return redirect('/admin-dashboard'); // If they're an admin redirect them to the admin dashboard.
    }

    return redirect('/home'); 
    // Otherwise proceed normally and redirect the user to the normal home or dashboard.
}
```

Of course you should extends this to include what if they user provided an invalid email, so you should redirect them back with the input and errors for example, hopefully this is similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: Will check this out as well. This looks like more of what i was looking for tho :D

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
if (auth()->user()->user_type == 2) {
    // Do admin stuff
}
```

Otherwise you can add a function in your `User.php`

```
public function getIsAdminAttribute()
{
    return $this->user_type == 2;
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
if (auth()->user()->is_admin) {
    // Do admin stuff
}
```

Comment: I will try this. So there is no way to like to do this in a controller? Like when the user loads a page it will check with a guard or something like a normal check auth page does?

Comment: @JarrodEstepp Yes you can add the if case inside a Guard. You can also put it into your Controller. Depends what you want to achieve.

Comment: Just browsing fast, different ways to do this. I am 2 weeks into laravel and am yet to make an authentication because i was stuck on this and how to login with a username instead of email.